# How to extract two files using Teamcity VCS and github

Tags: github, filter, version-control, teamcity

I need to extract only two files from a github repo, using a VCS in Teamcity.

I have found out how to do it for a subdirectory, but I'm not sure how to setup a filter that allows for multiple files, that a similarly named.

Here is how I write a filter for extracting all the files in a subdirectory:

`+:TeamcityScripts => TeamcityScripts/.`

Let's say the files are named: "Jeff" and "Jeff_Info.txt"

How would I write a VCS filter that only takes out files named: `Jeff*`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Rules in TeamCity only work on folders, not on files. VCS Triggers on the other hand work for single files aswell.

See also: [Feature Request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3460)

Comment: You are right, this is actually written underneath the filter-edit box.